# My Technically Incorrect Answer Accepted, Downvoted and Corrected

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

**TL:DR - My answer was accepted then downvoted. Although the answer has been corrected the downvotes remain. Is there anything I can/should do?**

Okay, here is my issue. Sorry if I waffle a little, you will have to bear with me.

I answered a question today on variable declaring scope for loops. As far as I can see, the answer was technically correct and helpful. I then added a small paragraph to the bottom about `String` concatenation adding objects to the `String` pool. To cut a long story short, that is only correct when concatenating `String` literals, which I hadn't specified.

The answer was then promptly accepted. Shortly after that I earnt myself a down-vote on that answer for not being specific enough about literal concatenation rather than variable concatenation. Fair enough. After a brief dialog I corrected the vagueness of the last paragraph. I then received second down-vote for the same reason despite the correction. I politely alerted the down-voters that I had removed the vague/unhelpful last paragraph but the down-votes were not removed. Again, fair enough, I can't expect people to run around checking their down-votes.

There is a selfish concern in that I don't like to have down-voted answers, I pride myself on keeping correct high quality answers. But there is also a more important concern. The most important concern is that if future visitors find this question they might assume that my answer is wrong and have to keep looking which means it will take them longer to find the answer they are looking for.

So the question now is - is there anything I can or should do about it? Or, should I leave the answer as it is? Any thoughts?

Edit: [Link to the answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23359015/2182928).

Comment: I'd say don't worry about it - it's great that you've gone back to correct it, but rep isn't everything. You could add a comment or an addendum to the answer to explain that you have modified it since it was first written. That said, I only do "Edit:" or "Updated:" sections in answers if they would be immediately useful to current readers, since they are a distraction to the bulk of future readers who are reading it for the first time - but that's a style preference, I think.

Comment: I might be wrong but both the question makes little sense.  If you need to concatenate the string in a loop, wouldn't declaring it within overwrite it?  That said, the answer could have been written more clearly.

Comment: @devnull - It is a bit wordy isn't it? I've changed the wording to be a little more concise. The question was fairly badly worded but at heart it seemed a question on variable scope and loop performance, so that's the angle I took with the answer. halfer - It's not really about the rep, it's more about future visitors doubting the answers correctness and therefore having to prolong their search.

Comment: The root problem seems to be that some people downvote too much. IMHO, downvotes should be used for answers that are downright wrong, not just because they could be more complete or clearer. Use upvotes for the best answers and leave the ones in the middle alone.

Comment: @Barmar, depends on what kind of community SO is trying to build here, and what is the real usefulness of the reputation score as an index of what? trustworthiness? accuracy? skill level?Right now, an up-vote on a response is a subjective combination of a lot of factors that are not defined or weighted consistently between users...  I would say, don't sweat it, or put links in your profile to a place where you can write the follow up to the down-vote event.  Explain there what the state was before and after the negative vote was cast.  You can't force down voters to take their opinions back.

Comment: What is the purpose of voting (up or down) on answers? I don't do it to help or hurt the poster's rep, I do it to help rank the answers. Good answers should float to the top, and incorrect answers should be pushed down. Answers in between can stay in the middle. The effect on the poster's rep is a useful side effect, but it's not what I'm thinking about when my hand is on the mouse.

Comment: @Barmar Boosting or lowering the poster's rep should be at least a component of the motivation, since the credibility of those posting answers is important, even if not as important as the credibility of an individual answer.

Comment: Ideally, if answers are edited they would go into some kind of review queue for each prior voter...so they could go back and see if that affected their vote.  But that wouldn't scale very well.  Maybe a button so concerned posters could nominate an edit as going into some *"I fixed it"* review queue.  The meta effect (just posting about it here) is the low-tech version of that, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just leave your answer as is, the correctest version that is. Don't edit your answer to be incorrect just because it has negative score. That is way over thinking things. There is no way for us to know if some guy/gal will visit your answer a year from now and say "Oh this answer has -1 score, I won't bother to read it since it must be wrong".

Fact is, since yours is the accepted answer that carries a lot of weight in and of itself. And the fact that yours is the only answer on that question. It's more likely that future guy/gal will analyze your answer themselves and choose to try it or not. It's fine to have some disagreements in the comment thread under your answer, and could possibly help future users learn even more.