# How to deal with incorrect answers on unpopular questions?

Tags: discussion

<sup>*This question may be considered biased by some, but the problem I describe is an actual source of woe-and-worry for me, and one that's been bugging me for quite a long time; the problem is not specific to Stack Overflow, but it's mostly visible here.*</sup>

---

There was a comment stating,

> "Some people" are wrong and you know it

And, more importantly,

> The only reason you didn't get any supportive voices is that the question you answered is borderline off-topic here (there are other SE sites for math questions) and is labeled with tags that few pay attention to. What I'm saying is, who cares?

... this made me think.

Imagine *(actually, you don't have to imagine, because that's actually happening all the time on SO)* that somebody posts a question that is either nontrivial because of its inherent difficulty or because of the little amount of documentation, support and userbase - and is, at the same time, concerning some kind of a "borderline" region (be that LISP programming, complex algorithmic problems or something similar).

Now, because of some luck (or appearing on the Hot list) the question actually gets some initial momentum (views) - and it receives some answers.

Since the problem is complicated or rare, most (if not all) of the initial answers are wrong. Some of the answers are purely wrong. Some are mediocre, but not entirely invalid, some are speculative. Most of them receive downvotes. Some posters delete their answers, while some remains.

Since the problem is complicated, the amount of daily views drops after the first short period.

Some people try to piece the information that's out there and create some valid answer.

Again, most of them are wrong, since the problem is, one way or another, complicated. This time, however, the initial *fun-factor* of the question has long since expired - nobody bothers with it anymore. The question gets little to no views, and the wrong answers get no votes.

Incidentally, somebody posts an answer a bit more valid than the others. It, too, gets essentially no votes, for the very same reason.

After a while, the *storm erupts; two or more of the authors of the wrong answers begin convincing each other they were, in fact, right, and begin upvoting their answers, downvoting other answers etc*.

They are given rational arguments why they are/may be wrong - but, for some *unknown* reason people don't actually *vote* on the answers. Maybe they aren't sure the answers are wrong; maybe they appreciate the answers' effort, even if the result is sub-par. Maybe something else, I don't know.

They are given solid reference(s), there are even parallel questions asked to provide them with the community's opinion; they either ignore it, call it *biased*, say *this is your opinion, I'm entitled to mine* (when dealing with *factual* information) etc.

The main questions are:

**Should I "fight" with such questions?**

If so, **how**? They aren't receiving attention, little people care about them, those who care at all don't want to get caught in the crossfire...

If not, **doesn't that affect Stack Exchange's informational quality**? After all, we have a wrong answer, upvoted seemingly valid. Anybody seeking an answer to this problem *and* considering Stack Overflow a *reliable source* would suffer.

I've [read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252713/my-technically-incorrect-answer-accepted-downvoted-and-corrected) that,

> IMHO, downvotes should be used for answers that are downright wrong, not just because they could be more complete or clearer. Use upvotes for the best answers and leave the ones in the middle alone.

Is that really the case?

Also, note that this is a direct example where *community consensus* means *no consensus*, because there is, essentially, *almost no community* caring about something enough.

---

Slightly related; [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers), and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) one, *sigh*, is probably more related to *why* I do have this problem, instead of the problem itself.

<sup>*For the sake of all parties involved, let's say the situation was imaginary and in no way related to my actual experience in the last 30 days.*</sup>

Comment: Do you have a specific example of such a question?

Comment: @Bruno `for the sake of all parties involved` I'd prefer to not point out to a specific example of such question, on the grounds I was one of the parties involved and thus may be considered biased *or* trying to make a point for that one particular case; I consider the problem broader than that one case, as I've seen similar things happening a dozen of times in the past.

Comment: The problem is that the general answer to your questions is *"It depends ..."*. You will get better answers with a few exampled to show. We understand that you are trying to talk about a big picture but it still helps to have some concrete reference points.

Comment: This seems such a speculative and complicated scenario -- and one that I don't recall coming across -- that I am just left wondering how often it happens without examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614798/find-the-number-of-distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table/24623343 is one such example from recent days. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590014/working-with-recursion/24590208 was another one. Those weren't isolated cases. I agree that they don't happen to *everybody* - it happens mostly in the particular scenario described above. Most people just doesn't care about such questions, that's all.

Comment: Well, the second one is generating problems because it's a vague request for mentoring; doesn't really fit in this format. That's also why it's closed, and I agree with the closure. The first one is better, but it's still borderline; it's all but explicitly generating discussion, and the features here really don't facilitate that. In fact, they're tuned against it. I think what you're seeing is just the interference pattern generated when a query is shoehorned into a poorly-fitting structure.

Comment: @JoshCaswell would you mind providing that as an answer? I think you've hit the nail with what you written...

Comment: Sure, I can come back to it later. My current keyboard and time allowance aren't going to let me flesh that out at all.

Comment: Oh look!  It's another "how do I deal with when people disagree with me on the quality of answers"

Comment: Treat it the exact same way that you would treat a brand new answer with no votes at all. Downvote if you think it's wrong, and flag it if you think it's not an answer or otherwise flaggable, just like you would were it new.

And if the answer remains upvoted, and you can't convince a moderator to remove it, then you're just going to have to live with the fact that you're not the sole decider of correctness around here, and that more people disagree with you about the answer than agree with you.

Comment: @SamIam I am not talking about a case when it's about "agreeing"; I already stated that in the first paragraph - it's not about a case when there's, for example, 100 people disagreeing with me and 5 people agreeing - it's about a case when, e.g. 5 people agree with me one way or another, 2 people disagree, those 5 people don't care about the matter enough to get involved, those 2 people involve themselves 100% into the matter; I already said, the value of community consensus is void when there's no community on the matter, do you understand the difference between this and what you written?

Comment: @vaxquis if those 5 people truly agreed with you then they'd be downvoting.  It's clear that they're not sure enough about their agreement

Comment: @SamIam exactly. Haven't you noticed that when dealing with a difficult problem people who are wrong are usually the ones most convinced they are right? It's a type of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_superiority namely, with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect also coming to mind. In short - if the population sample is small enough, the overconfident & *wrong* minory can easily overcome the underconfident & *right* majority. The problem has been described countless times in psychological papers, and is far from imaginary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't recall having seen what you describe, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that you've seen it play out on enough occasions to be worrying you.

You linked two examples in a comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24590014/ (10k-only link) and [Find the number of distinct numbers in multiplication table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614798/find-the-number-of-distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table/24623343)

The first one was already closed when I looked at it earlier, and is now deleted. With good reason: it's a vague request for mentoring. The poster has a homework-like problem that e's struggling with, has gotten mired at a particular point, and is up to eir neck in it, with no view of a way forward. This happens to all of us, and it's perfectly okay to ask for help in that situation, but the features of Stack Overflow don't support it.

The OP needs an extensive back-and-forth with a tutor; answers on Stack Overflow are just the straight-up solution to your coding problem. That conflict is playing itself out as expected: a few people provided full code solutions to the OP's task, and someone else is downvoting the answers, because they're providing the "wrong kind", or "too much" help. On the other hand, answers that only give vague guidance aren't especially good Stack Overflow answers, because the next person who comes along isn't going to be able to use them. What's an answerer to do here? There's no good option, and it's because of the question.*

The second one is a little better, but it's still on the open-ended side of the fence. It's really looking for a discussion of the problem, requiring a back-and-forth among experts to hash out a solution. The features of the website were designed and tuned *against* discussion. The incorrect answers may be valid points along the way, but they don't hold up as the final, complete solutions we expect on Stack Overflow. So some people downvote them, which -- as Robert pointed out -- is exactly what we do with incorrect answers, and other people get owies in their heinies about that, because they're just participating in the kind of interaction the question initiated.

If these truly are representative of the situation you're talking about, then I think what you're seeing is simply the interference pattern generated when an open-ended query is shoehorned into the Stack Exchange format, which won't support that kind of discourse. It's not the answers that are at fault; it's the questions. Don't worry too much about the former; focus on getting the questions closed, deleted, and moved to a more appropriate platform if necessary.

---

*We've had multiple discussions in the past about "homework" questions -- whether they should be disallowed, how they should be answered -- for precisely this reason.

Comment: thanks, Josh, I think this mostly covers the problem at hand... still, the fact that the amount of questions "nobody cares" increases is not that motivating; not at all, I'd say...

Answer (score 7):

By downvoting them.

No, really. Downvote them.

You were expecting something more ingenious?

Comment: downvoting *whom*? The questions? The answers? The users? ... the main point of my question was, *how to deal with cases when voting system fails for a systemic reason*; the answer "downvote them" is, well, kind of *uncalled for* here. But yes, I was expecting something more ingenious - and the fun fact is, somebody in this thread actually *did* that...

Comment: So what sort of action do you expect on the first example you provided?  (I already deleted the second one, as it was already closed and, well, kind of useless).  What do you expect us to do about it?

Comment: [joke] *and there goes another handful of hard earned points* [/joke] I didn't expect any action per se ; your deletion made me feel kind of awkward... I expected something like that would happen when I posted the link. Still - while the question was, in fact, trivial - it was fun to solve, and was, kind of... legit. OP asked for a way to solve a problem with recursion, he got just that. Dunno if it deserved a close, maybe? Still, I didn't ask *for an administrative action*, I asked for *an explanation and systemic solution*.

Comment: The explanation is human nature.  People vote on things they like; that's not really how the voting system is supposed to work, but that's the way it is. There is no systemic solution, unless you have a suggestion that has eluded me.  Drawing and quartering, perhaps?

Comment: since you proposed an actual argument, I'd gladly give you my *precioussss* upvote if you'd kindly include your last comment in your answer, preferrably with the "Drawing and quartering" part intact. *Hanging too, mayhap?*

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a scenario where basically the majority of visitors and voters has no idea but still votes.

Well in this scenario the helpfulness of the score is lowered and resembles noise.

As a user facing the same problem you can still test all solutions and then take the working one

If then you would also upvote the working answer and downvote all the failing ones that would be nice. Clarifying comments are also welcome.

Given time the situation corrects itself as long as there is at least someone who knows or tests the right answers.

Summary: Don't use answers from SO in security critical applications without extensive testing!

Comment: `as long as there is at least someone who knows or tests the right answers` - as we already seen, the amount of such people (interested in strange, borderline cases) is getting a significantly lower % of users each year - and, sadly, it's also something that gets me worried... 3-4 years ago SO worked like a charm - today, I feel that the quality of both the questions and the results of voting is getting lower by the day...

Comment: @vaxquis You could maybe weigh the votes by rep but that would require constant re-calculation of the weights. On the other hand: if nobody is interested in border cases anymore then nobody is. If you see such a question it's your job to downvote all wrong answers and upvote the right ones. What more can we do?

Comment: personally, a system when *least* viewed questions are frontpaged instead of *most* viewed could work wonders in terms of site quality... one more obvious duplicate of an obvious question in Hot Questions with literal dozens of votes cast (don't say you haven't seen at least one on SO... not that dupe queue work good ATM - I've dupes marked a year ago, still active), and I'm honestly going to DDoS somebody.

Comment: @vaxquis You can give [a range of views](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A0-10) in the search mask .. that actually doesn't really work. I only wanted questions with 0-10 views and got questions with 0-20 views. Probably not often enough updated.